Error in sklearn’s cross_val_score with ‘f1’ scoring for categorical target in LightGBM
My code receives a dataset and runs a classification on it with lightgbm. The problem is when I try to do fine-tuning with sklearn's cross_val_score, the target column contains categorical values, not numerical ones.
It works when I set the cross_val_score to work with accuracy, log loss, roc_auctype scoring. On the other hand, when I set it to work with scoring of f1, precision, recall, I get an error. Below is an example when I try to classify the iris dataset:
The code:
cv_results = cross_val_score(estimator, self.X_train, self.y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='f1')

The error:
ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: It should be one of

['Iris-setosa' 'Iris-versicolor' 'Iris-virginica']

Thanks

Hello @Zag Gol! Did my answer help you? If so, I'd appreciate if you could accept it
